# Showing text in a div in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a chat app where I want to show some text on a `chatbox` div

```
<div id="chatbox"></div>
<input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
<button name="submitmsg" id="submitmsg">Send</button>
```

The UI looks like the attached image. The chatbox div includes the white area (including the left, right and bottom margin).

CSS

```
#chatbox {
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    height:270px;
    width:430px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
    overflow:auto; }
```

Now when I receive a message on socket, I want to write it to that `chatbox` div.

```
socket.on('reply', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
    $('#chatbox').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text(msg).html());
    });
```

I know the socket is working properly as I see the message in javascript console. But the message is not coming to the `chatbox` div (or at least I am not seeing).

What am I missing?

[image]

EDIT: working sample

index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "chatBubble" type="submit" class="talk-bubble tri-right btm-right round">
        <div class="talktext">
          <p>Hi, can I help?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="wrapper" display='none'>
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome<b></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox"></div>
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <button name="submitmsg" id="submitmsg">Send</button>
    </div>
```

index.css

```
#chatbox {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 270px;
  width: 430px;
  border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.talk-bubble {
    margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
.border{
  border: 8px solid #666;
}
.round{
  border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;

}

.tri-right.btm-right-in:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  left: auto;
    right: 38px;
    bottom: -20px;
    border: 12px solid;
    border-color: lightyellow lightyellow transparent transparent;
}

.tri-right.btm-right:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  left: auto;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -20px;
    border: 12px solid;
    border-color: lightyellow lightyellow transparent transparent;
}

/* talk bubble contents */
.talktext{
  padding: 1em;
    text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  /*position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;*/
}
.talktext p{
  /* remove webkit p margins */
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
}

#wrapper{
        margin:0 auto;
        padding-bottom:25px;
        background:#EBF4FB;
        width:504px;
        border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }
        .welcome { float:left; }

        .logout { float:right; }
```

server.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

def fromConsumer(msg):
    print ("at from consumer")
    print(msg)
    socketio.emit('reply', msg)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',)

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):

    print('Server got: ' + msg)
    replyData = "How are you"
    fromConsumer(replyData)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper').hide();
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1000/');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("connected")
    });
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log('Received message');
    });
  socket.on('reply', function(msg) {
        console.log('Received reply');
    console.log(msg)
    $('#chatbox').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text(msg).html());
    });
  $('#submitmsg').on('click', function() {
        socket.send($('#usermsg').val());
        $('#usermsg').val('');
    });
  $("#chatBubble").click(function(){
    $('#wrapper').show();
  })
});
```

Comment: Provided that you receive a `msg` string, as you confirmed, your code [seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/yj632854/). Can you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the issue?

Comment: It works just fine. Maybe you should debug msg first.

Comment: @showdev added working sample

Comment: `<div/>` certainly is NOT valid HTML code, a div needs an opening and closing tag

Comment: What does `console.log(msg)` show?

Comment: @showdev it shows `How are you`

Comment: @Johannes I tried `$('#chatbox').append(msg);` too but doesn't show the message

Comment: @Johannes in jQuery `$('<div/>')` _is_ valid - it creates an empty `div` HTMLElement. `$('<div/>').text(msg)` creates the element and sets the text content of it. Finally in `$('<div/>').text(msg).html()` the `.html()` gets the html markup of the content of the created div, _but **not** the `<div></div>` itself_ (which may be the problem with the code.)

Comment: As others have said, when I try this just in the browser console it seems to work fine -- `$('div#test').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text(msg).html());` (where I've set `var msg='hi there';`) ... although personally I'd do it as `.append('<br>').append($('<div/>').text(msg));` because jQuery append will append elements, so turning it back into a string and concatenating is unnecessary.

Comment: @showdev it works fine now. I needed to clear the browser cache!